# JSON returns [null,null] in my app

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, database

I want to send database records with a PHPH file via json to my app I am making with IntelXDK. Because I can't use PHP code with the Intel XDK, I needed to use JSON. I want to show the two records 'quote' and 'author' from my 'quotes' table on my screen. Someone helped me to this code but it just returns [null,null]instead of the two records I need.. I tried debugging but I am new to PHP so I can'get it to work.. Anyone who can help or sees an error in this code? Thanks!

PS: Yes I now there are already multiple questions asked on this subject by other people. I have read them all but none of them solves my question..

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_GET["get_rows"]))
    {
        //checks the format client wants
        if($_GET["get_rows"] == "json")
        {
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx");

            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo mysqli_connect_error();
                header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
                exit();
            }

            $query = "SELECT quote, author FROM quotes WHERE id = " . date('d');

            $jsonData = array();

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

                /* fetch associative array */
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);

            // Create a new array and assign the column values to it
             // You can either turn an associative array or basic array
            $ret= array();

            $ret[] = $row['quote']; 
            $ret[] = $row['author']; 

                //encode to JSON format

                echo  json_encode($ret);

            }

            else {

                echo  json_encode($ret);
            }

            /* close connection */
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
        else
        {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in `fetch_assoc()` function call -  remove `$result` parameter. If you had error reporting enabling, you should see:

> Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Just change it to:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

In javascript to parse this response, just do this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = obj[0];
document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = obj[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I now get ["quote","author"], I actually need quote and author to be two seperate strings without "" and [].. 

My json outputs this: echo  json_encode($ret);
The script on my html files uses this: document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
To output the string in the <div id="quote"></div> 

Do you know how I can make json output two strings, so the 'quote' and the 'author' and make the script output hem in two different <div>'s? That would totally fix my entire problem.. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! This finally works perfect! What a great community here!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
```

to

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Just change it to:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

**Updated:**

```
response =  JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

you can now access them independently as:

`reponse.quote` and `response.author`

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I now get ["quote","author"], I actually need quote and author to be two seperate strings without "" and [].. 

My json outputs this: echo  json_encode($ret);
The script on my html files uses this: document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
To output the string in the <div id="quote"></div> 

Do you know how I can make json output two strings, so the 'quote' and the 'author' and make the script output hem in two different <div>'s? That would totally fix my entire problem.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with fetch_assoc()
Try to use that :

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

instead of

```
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
```

It's works for me with your example

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I now get ["quote","author"], I actually need quote and author to be two seperate strings without "" and [].. My json outputs this: echo json_encode($ret); The script on my html files uses this: document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; To output the string in the <div id="quote"></div> Do you know how I can make json output two strings, so the 'quote' and the 'author' and make the script output hem in two different <div>'s? That would totally fix my entire problem.. Thanks! –